# Restrict maximum number of records of specific type

Tags: workflow, process-builder, validation, automation

**Requirements**

I need to have a validation on a custom object for maximum records of specific  **Type**.

**Example**

Record1 - TypeArticle - count=2

Record2 - TypeArticle - count=2

Record3 - TypeVideo - count=1

In the above example, counter has reseted with `Type` changed, and since there are 2 records with `Type`=`Article`, hence count=2. So, with every subsequent type record insertion the count would increase or decrease if the records are deleted.

**What have I tried so far?**

I am in the middle of developing a Process builder, as I wanted to have multiple decision routes, which are not available in workflows, but kinda stuck on how to show count of records on the basis of a field, which in my case is `Type__c`. A rollup summary tool would've been easier, but it doesn't allow to create on the same object.

I don't wanna develop **trigger** for this. I am looking for any out-of-the-box automation

Comment: I think you need `Apex` for this one.

Comment: Damn!!! This is exactly what I don't want.

Comment: you can try with visual workflows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to write code for this you can use the Declarative Rollup Summaries package for easy counts or even more complex calculations.

Check it out  [here].[1](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries)

The good thing is that all is included for you and can be install in any type of environment.

It contains an important number of configurations options. Maybe you can run your logic using this package.

I hope it helps.